# VkLayerSettingEXT example to enable khronos_validation.validate_gpu_based and khronos_validation.printf_to_stdout

Tags: vulkan, validation-layers

How VkLayerSettingEXT should look like to enable khronos_validation.validate_gpu_based and khronos_validation.printf_to_stdout, because there is no VK_LAYER_SETTING_TYPE_*_EXT for enums.

I am referring to https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.275.0/linux/layer_configuration.html
and https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/linux/khronos_validation_layer.html

I tried with no luck

```
const char* layer_name = "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation";
const char* gpu_based = "GPU_BASED_DEBUG_PRINTF";
VkBool32 enable_stdout = true;
const vk::LayerSettingEXT settings[]
{
    {layer_name, "validate_gpu_based", vk::LayerSettingTypeEXT::eString, 1, &gpu_based},
    {layer_name, "printf_to_stdout", vk::LayerSettingTypeEXT::eBool32, 1, &enable_stdout},
};
vk::LayerSettingsCreateInfoEXT layer_settings_create_info{static_cast<uint32_t>(std::size(settings)),settings,nullptr};
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used vulkan.hpp so I might be missing something but:

```
vk::LayerSettingsCreateInfoEXT layer_settings_create_info{static_cast<uint32_t>(std::size(settings)),settings,nullptr};
```

Looks weird to me as the sType is missing and I don't understand what this nullptr at the end.

With vulkan.h the initialization would look like:

```
const VkLayerSettingsCreateInfoEXT layer_settings_create_info = {
VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_LAYER_SETTINGS_CREATE_INFO_EXT, nullptr,
static_cast<uint32_t>(std::size(settings)), settings};
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, but problem is with setting vk::LayerSettingEXT with validate_gpu_based